# Get coordinate-wise maximum out of 3 matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

Suppose I have 3 matrices **A**, **B** ,**C**. I want to create new matrix which will contain maximum value of  matrices.

For example let

```
A = [ a11 a12.. ] B = [b11 b12 ..] C = [c11 c12 ..]
    [ a21 a22.. ]     [b21 b22 ..]     [c21 c22 ..]
```

I want new matrix be constructed this way

```
NewMatr = [max(a11,b11,c11) max(a12,b12,c12) .. ]
          [max(a21,b21,c21) max(a22,b22,c22) .. ]
```

I thought of combining them into new matrix which will contain 3x1 vectors and applying max to this new matrix but i don't know how. Pf course there is always for method but i'm running for optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to concatenating, you can use the 2-input version of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), twice:

```
max(max(A,B),C)
```

From the `max` docs regarding this somewhat uncommon syntax:

> `C = max(A,B)` returns an array the same size as `A` and `B` with the largest elements taken from `A` or `B`. The dimensions of `A` and `B` must match, or they may be scalar.

Comment: MAX documentation mostly stated that it returns maximum value of a vector and didn't notice two-dimensional variant.

Answer (score 1):

Concat along third dim (with [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)) and then compute maximum along that dim (with [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html)):

```
NewMatr = max(cat(3,A,B,C),[],3);
```